# how can I change float to percentage with specific precision python

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, percentage

I'd like to change float values to percent with precision of 3 decimal points.

This is what I tried:

```
df.style.format('var3': "{:.3%}",'var1': "{:.3%}",'var4': "{:.3%}", 'var5': "{:.3%}"})
display(df)
```

this is what I'm getting:

**input:**

var1:   0.0092592592592592

**output**

var1 : 0.900%

This is what I would like o get as output:

**var1: 0.926%**

Appreciate the help..

Comment: Not my down vote, but `'{:.3%}'.format(.0092592592592592)` gives `0.926%` on my system.

Comment: Please, add [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
df[col].map('{:.3%}'.format)